# Can Api.ai use a service other than Firebase and if so what are some examples?

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Exactly as the question says, I'm getting to the fulfilment stage of API.AI development and I don't want my user's data going through Google's Firebase, so will API.AI allow me to use my own web service?

Comment: May I ask why there is confusion about this?  Did you read something that suggests Firebase is the only way to create a fulfillment hook for API.AI?

Comment: @Sukh gave the correct answer. If you wish to see an example for an API.AI fulfilment both in JS and php check this repo I've created: https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action

Answer (score 7):

Yes, api.ai allows you create your own web service.

You can create a server with any programming language which support rest services for e.g. Web server with nodeJs or spring-boot

Other then that, google has their own nodeJs client library which has all the pre work done for develpers

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp